# File not found after a directory copy

Tags: python, linux, systemd

I'm trying to create an install script with Python to create a daemon using `systemd`.

**Exctract of install script:**

```
....
# Copy ProcessManager directory into /usr/local/bin/
print('Copy sources into /usr/local/bin')
os.system('cp -r ' + processManagerPath + ' /usr/local/bin')

fileContent =   '[Unit] \n' \
                'Description=ProcessManager \n' \
                'After=tlp-init.service \n\n' \
                '[Service] \n' \
                'Type=oneshot \n' \
                'RemainAfterExit=no \n' \
                'ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/ProcessManager/gobatch.py \n\n' \
                '[Install] \n' \
                'WantedBy=multi-user.target'

file = open('/etc/systemd/system/processManager.service', 'w')
file.write(fileContent)
file.close()
....
```

However, when I start my daemon with: `sudo systemctl status processManager.service` I get this error:

```
    stringToSend = convertFileToString()
  File "/usr/local/bin/ProcessManager/gobatch.py", line 23, in convertFileToString
    fbatchContent = readFile()
  File "/usr/local/bin/ProcessManager/gobatch.py", line 13, in readFile
    with open("FBatch", "r") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FBatch'
```

And when I list `/usr/local/bin/ProcessManager` the content is:

```
FBatch  findCommand.py  gobatch.py  install.py  Programs.md  UpdateFBatchFile.py
```

It exists something that I don't know about `cp -r`? or about privileges?

Thank's for help!

Comment: Are you certain the working directory is `/usr/local/bin/ProcessManager`? `with open("FBatch", "r") as f:` will try to open a file in the current working directory.

Comment: Yes I think because my command exec is `ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/ProcessManager/gobatch.py`. Am I wrong?

Comment: I would suggest either putting the fullpath in the parameter for the filename or debugging with `print(os.cwd())`

Comment: I got an error : `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cwd'`. Same result with `os.pwd`. When I print os.system('pwd') nothing happens except the error... And the file is update directly with nano.

Comment: sorry, it is `os.getcwd()`; my mistake

Comment: `os.getcwd()` returns `/` but my file `gobatch.py` isn't here... I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attempt `with open("FBatch", "r") as f:`, it will not try to open the file in `/usr/local/bin/ProcessManager`, as it is not the current working directory. Instead it will try to open it somewhere else. In this case it tried to open the file in the root directory `/`.

You will either have to provide a full path for all of your `open` calls, or use `os.chdir(path)` once to change the current working directory.

Comment: Use `os.chdir(/usr/local/bin/ProcessManager`) in the beginning of my script seems to works! Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

As everybody has already pointed out the problem is with the current working path, you can solve it with `os.chdir` in you python script, or you can specify `WorkingDirectory` in your unit file so it will look like:

```
fileContent =   '[Unit] \n' \
            'Description=ProcessManager \n' \
            'After=tlp-init.service \n\n' \
            '[Service] \n' \
            'Type=oneshot \n' \
            'WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/ProcessManager\n' \
            'RemainAfterExit=no \n' \
            'ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/ProcessManager/gobatch.py \n\n' \
            '[Install] \n' \
            'WantedBy=multi-user.target'
```

also if you dont want your script to survive restart you can use [pystemd](https://github.com/facebookincubator/pystemd) library to start a transient unit.

```
import pystemd.run

pystemd.run([b'/usr/bin/python', b'/usr/local/bin/ProcessManager/gobatch.py'], cwd=b'/usr/local/bin/ProcessManager')
```

in all fairness you can do the same with systemd-run command-line tool